# R: how to use apply to loop over variables in a data.frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply, sapply

I'm trying to learn how to use apply (or any other members of the family of apply) to loop over variables in a data.frame

For example: say I have the following data.frame

```
    df_long <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
             country=c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'),
             year=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
             amt = c(3,4,23,5,76,5,2,3,5,4,6,2))
```

and I want to loop through all the variables such that if the variable is numeric, then I had one to it, else I do nothing. I want the return variable to be a data.frame.
This is what I have so far but it doesn't work

```
    apply(df_long, 2, function(x) x = ifelse(is.numeric(x), x+1, x))
```

Any insights on this question or in general how to loop through variables in a data.frame using apply and/or other methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be of help to understand how to apply a function to specific columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with `sapply` and `apply` to follow the method that you have originally asked for but the challenge with that is that it is trying to coerce the result into to a matrix. Which is either forcing all variables to be returned as characters or it is converting the `country` variable into numeric and is converting `a` to `1`, `b` to `2` and so on.

If you prefer a single line of code using one of the `apply` functions then I recommend using `lapply`. `lapply` will return the result as a list, which can then be converted to a dataframe. A solution is below:

```
as.data.frame(
  lapply(
    df_long, 
    function(col) 
      if(is.numeric(col)) {col + 1} else {col}))
```

The result is:

```
   id country year amt
1   2       a    2   4
2   2       a    3   5
3   2       a    4  24
4   2       a    5   6
5   3       b    2  77
6   3       b    3   6
7   3       b    4   3
8   3       b    5   4
9   4       c    2   6
10  4       c    3   5
11  4       c    4   7
12  4       c    5   3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first find columns which are numeric using `is.numeric` and then add 1 to only those columns. `sapply/lapply` loops over each column and returns TRUE/FALSE if the columns is numeric or not. We use that logical indices (`col_ind`) to subset the dataframe and add a 1 to it.

```
col_ind <- sapply(df_long, is.numeric)
df_long[col_ind] <- df_long[col_ind] + 1
df_long

#   id country year amt
#1   2       a    2   4
#2   2       a    3   5
#3   2       a    4  24
#4   2       a    5   6
#5   3       b    2  77
#6   3       b    3   6
#7   3       b    4   3
#8   3       b    5   4
#9   4       c    2   6
#10  4       c    3   5
#11  4       c    4   7
#12  4       c    5   3
```

---

Possibly a more simpler approach with `dplyr` in one-liner.

```
library(dplyr)
df_long %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(. + 1))
```