# How to generate multiple similar ggplots together

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

Most of the answers available refer to combining multiple ggplots together. I'm trying to generate multiple ggplots together.
I have generated bar diagrams for multiple variables separately and then used 'ggarrange' to combine them together.

## Create a sample dataset

```
y0 = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0)
x1 = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","A")
x2 = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2)
x3 = c("A","B","C","D","E","E","D","C","B","A")
df<- data.frame(y0,x1,x2,x3);
df
```

## calculate statistics for x1 variable

```
x1_count <- df %>% 
group_by(x1) %>%
summarise(Count=n(), Num=sum(y0))  %>%
mutate(Rate=Num/Count*100.0)
```

## generate ggplot for x1 vaiable

```
A<- ggplot(x1_count, aes(x=x1, y=Rate)) +
geom_bar(width=0.5, stat="identity") +
ggtitle('Rate by x1') +
xlab("x1") +
ylab("Rate (%)") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position='bottom')
```

## calculate statistics for x2 variable

```
x2_count <- df %>% 
  group_by(x2) %>%
  summarise(Count=n(), Num=sum(y0))  %>%
  mutate(Rate=Num/Count*100.0)
```

## generate ggplot for x2 vaiable

```
B<- ggplot(x2_count, aes(x=x2, y=Rate)) +
  geom_bar(width=0.5, stat="identity") +
  ggtitle('Rate by x2') +
  xlab("x2") +
  ylab("Rate (%)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position='bottom') 
B
```

## combine them together

```
figure1 <- ggarrange(A,B,ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
figure1
```

I'm trying to generate ggplots A and B, and the calculations associated with it together rather than doing it separately.

Comment: It seems like you might want to make a function that does the summarizing and plotting that you can then use in a loop, looping through the names of the variables and returning a list of plots.  While simpler than what you are doing (since I didn't do any summarizing), I wrote up an example of making many plots using a function and `purrr::map()` loops [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/) that you might find relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are repeating the same task you can create a function where you simply need to place the values you want to calculate or graph into the function.

For your calculation you could:

```
counting <- function(variable(x1 or x2)){ 
df %>% 
  group_by{{variable}} %>% 
  mutate(Rate=Num/Count*100.0)}
```

Variable is where you put the specific variable of interest. Next you could create a function to generate a ggplot for each variable using the function above:

```
graphic <- function(variable){ 
 counting({{variable}}) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = {{variable}}, y = Rate)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5, stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Rate (%)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, 
        legend.postion = 'bottom')}
```

After doing that, you can then create a graphic for each variable by doing:

```
graphic(x1) +
 xlab("x1")

graphic(x2)
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function.

An R function has the following structure:

```
name <- function(argument) {
    what the function does
}
```

Considering that your plotting workflow is creating an additional variable and then plotting it, your could set your function argument to be the original dataframe `df` and then make the function do with it the `dplyr` and `ggplot2` commands:

```
myfunction <- function(df) {
  # creating new variable
  x_count <- df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(Count=n(), Num=sum(y0)) %>%
  mutate(Rate=Num/Count*100.0)

  # creating the plot
  plotX <- ggplot(x_count, aes(x=x, y=Rate)) +
  geom_bar(width=0.5, stat="identity") +
  ggtitle('Rate by x') +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("Rate (%)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust =     0.5),legend.position='bottom') 

  # showing the plot
  print(plotX)
}
```

Comment: Hi i need both A and B done together into one single function

Comment: Use `lapply` to create a loop with your two variables and the function I proposed in my answer.

Comment: Is the loop be within the function or outside the function?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `reshape` of your data from wide to long (the preferred format of most analytical methods), then `aggregate` for *Rate* calculation and `ggplot` with `facet_wrap`:

**`reshape`**

```
rdf <- reshape(transform(df, x2 = as.character(x2)), 
               varying = list(names(df)[-1]), v.names = "Value",
               times = names(df)[-1], timevar = "Categ",
               new.row.names = 1:1E3, direction="long")
rdf

#    y0 Categ Value id
# 1   1    x1     A  1
# 2   0    x1     B  2
# 3   1    x1     A  3
# 4   1    x1     B  4
# 5   0    x1     A  5
# 6   1    x1     B  6
# 7   0    x1     A  7
# 8   1    x1     B  8
# 9   1    x1     A  9
# 10  0    x1     A 10
# 11  1    x2     1  1
# 12  0    x2     2  2
# 13  1    x2     2  3
# 14  1    x2     1  4
# 15  0    x2     1  5
# 16  1    x2     2  6
# 17  0    x2     2  7
# 18  1    x2     1  8
# 19  1    x2     2  9
# 20  0    x2     2 10
# 21  1    x3     A  1
# 22  0    x3     B  2
# 23  1    x3     C  3
# 24  1    x3     D  4
# 25  0    x3     E  5
# 26  1    x3     E  6
# 27  0    x3     D  7
# 28  1    x3     C  8
# 29  1    x3     B  9
# 30  0    x3     A 10
```

**`aggregate`**

```
agg_raw <- aggregate(y0 ~ Categ + Value, rdf, 
                    function(x) c(Num=sum(x), Count=length(x),
                                  Rate=sum(x)/length(x) * 100.00))
agg_df <- do.call(data.frame, agg_raw)
agg_df <- setNames(agg_df, gsub("y0.", "", names(agg_df)))
agg_df

#   Categ Value Num Count Rate
# 1    x1     A   3     6   50
# 2    x3     A   1     2   50
# 3    x1     B   3     4   75
# 4    x3     B   1     2   50
# 5    x2     1   3     4   75
# 6    x2     2   3     6   50
# 7    x3     C   2     2  100
# 8    x3     D   1     2   50
# 9    x3     E   1     2   50
```

**`ggplot` + `facet_wrap`**

```
ggplot(agg_df, aes(x=Value, y=Rate)) +
  geom_bar(width=0.5, stat="identity") +
  ggtitle('Rate by x1') +
  xlab("x1") +
  ylab("Rate (%)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position='bottom') +
  facet_wrap(~Categ, ncol=2, scales="free_x")
```

[image: Plot Output]

Answer (score 1):

The excact same solution as Parfait but using more contemporary functions from the `tidyverse`

The data

```
library(tidyverse)
y0 = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0)
x1 = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","A")
x2 = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2)
x3 = c("A","B","C","D","E","E","D","C","B","A")
df<- data.frame(y0,x1,x2,x3)
```

reshape and aggregate

```
res<-
df %>% 
  tidyr::gather("Categ", "Value", x1, x2, x3) %>% 
  group_by(Categ, Value) %>% 
  summarise(Num=sum(y0),
            Count=length(y0),
            Rate=sum(y0)/length(y0) * 100.00)
```

Plot

```
  ggplot(res, aes(x=Value, y=Rate)) +
  geom_bar(width=0.5, stat="identity") +
  ggtitle('Rate by x1') +
  xlab("x1") +
  ylab("Rate (%)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position='bottom') +
  facet_wrap(~Categ, ncol=2, scales="free_x")
```