# How to create a function for a bar chart with percentage labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, r-markdown

I would like to create a function for a bar chart that contains labels with the respective percentages.

The following code creates the bar chart that I would like to see:

```r
percentData <- df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  count(col2) %>% 
  mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n)))

diagram <- ggplot(df, aes(x=col1, fill=col2)) 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") 
  geom_text(data=percentData, aes(y=n,label=ratio),
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

I would like to create a function for the bar chart above to be able to change `df`, `col1` and `col2`.

I tried the following:

```r
newdiagram <- function(data, col1, col2){
  percentData <- data %>% 
    group_by(col1) %>% 
    count(col2) %>% 
    mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n)))

  diagram <- ggplot(data, aes(x=col1, fill=col2)) 
    geom_bar(position = "fill") 
    geom_text(data=percentData, aes(y=n,label=ratio), 
              position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
  return(diagram)
}

newdiagram(df, column1, column2)
```

Unfortunately I receive the error message that the columns are unknown. I tried to solve it with specifying the columns with `data$col1` but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any sample data I'm not able to vertify to 100% percent that it will solve the issue but generaly speaking if you want to adress a column of a dataframe with a string this would be the right syntax:

```
data[[col1]]
```

which would mean that this should work for you:

```
newdiagram <- function(data, col1, col2){
  percentData <- data %>% 
    group_by(data[[col1]]) %>% 
    count(data[[col2]]) %>% 
    mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n)))

  diagram <- ggplot(data, aes(x=col1, fill=col2)) 
    geom_bar(position = "fill") 
    geom_text(data=percentData, aes(y=n,label=ratio), 
              position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
  return(diagram)
}

newdiagram(df, column1, column2)
```

Also you can provide a minimalistic data set for reproducability with:

```
head(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you separate the calculating of the percentages and building of the visual into two separate functions. Makes it easier to spot errors that way.

Using the syntax known as the curly brackets will help with this:

```
{{ }}
```

Calculating percentages

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(magrittr)

 percentData_calculation <- function(col1){
 group_by({{col1}}) %>%
 count({{col1}}) %>%
 mutate(ratio = scales::percent(n/sum(n)))}
```

Building visual

```
newdiagram <- function(df, col1, col2){
 percentData_calculation({{col1}}) %>%
  ggplot({{df}}, aes(x={{col1}},y={{col2}}) +
  geom_bar(postion = fill) +
  geom_text(., aes(y = n , label = ration),
          postion = postion_fill(vjust = 0.5)
```

In geom_text you don't need to name the data source since its coming from the calculation. Also if you know some aspect of the ggplot wont change, like the df, than you don't need to place it in the function.

Hope this help!

Comment: This other post might be of help too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298510/how-to-generate-multiple-similar-ggplots-together/57314675#57314675