# R using apply function instead of a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Very simple problem I'm trying to solve, just can't seem to figure it out.
I want to apply a certain criteria which is in a column to a number of columns.

```
cols_to_change<-['d','e','f']
```

for one column, d, i can do this:

```
df$d[which(df$criteria<df$d)]<-NA
```

But for the other columns,e,f, I could do a for loop, but I wanted to use an apply function instead. How can I do this?

Comment: Unclear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `cols_to_change<-['d','e','f']` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Apply() function on specific dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns)

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns

I've tagged this questions as a duplicate

Comment: Please use proper R syntax and provide a complete example including input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data it is difficult to validate what you are trying to do. Anyways, I think you are looking for something like the following

```
cols_to_change <- c("d", "e", "f")
df[cols_to_change] <- lapply(df[cols_to_change], function(x) ifelse(df$criteria < x, NA, x))
```

Note that `lapply` is a preferred version with respect to `apply`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i was after. I need to learn how to use this functions, it's quite confusing for me!

Comment: Just have a look at the documentation and practice, it's the most efficient way to learn :)