# character to numeric conversion problem in R

Tags: r

I have a big time series dataset in which the numeric results are stored in `General` format in `MS-Excel`. I tried using `gsub(",", "", dummy )`, but it did not work. The dataset does not have any `,` or any other visible special character other than a decimal point, and `R` picks up the `datatype` as `character`. Values are either `positive` or `negative` with one `NA` and all values have different number of decimal places.

How can I convert without having to deal with `N/As` after converting to numeric. One thing to note though is that when converted to numeric, some of the values are displayed in scientific notation like `12.1 e+03` and other values with four decimal places.

```
dummy = c("12.1", "42000", "1.2145", "12.25", N/A, "323.369", "-1.235", "335", "0")

# Convert to numeric   
dummy = gsub(",", "", dummy ) 
dummy = as.numeric(dummy )
```

Error

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion "
```

Comment: This could probably be sorted at an earlier stage, when you are importing your data e.g. `read.table(..., na.strings=c("", "N/A"))`. Then it is likely that this data will be imported as numeric (ps the coercion is a warning and not an error; that is, running `as.numeric(dummy)` gives the correct answer in this case (after changing `N/A` in your example to `"N/A"`). pps your example strings have no commas and so the `gsub` is not required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `N/A` to `NA` solves this issue:

```
# N/A to NA
dummy = c("12.1", "42000", "1.2145", "12.25", NA, "323.369", "-1.235", "335")

# Convert to numeric
dummy = gsub(",", "", dummy) 
dummy = as.numeric(dummy)
```

To do so for your entire dataset, you can use:

```
# Across columns (for matrices)
data <- apply(data, 2, function(x){
ifelse(x == "N/A", NA, x)
})

# Then convert characters to numeric (for matrices)
data <- apply(data, 2, as.numeric)

# Across columns (for data frames)
data <- lapply(data, function(x){
ifelse(x == "N/A", NA, x)
})

# Then convert characters to numeric (for data frames)
data <- lapply(data, as.numeric)
```

Update: `*apply` differences for object types in R -- thanks to user20650 for pointing this out

Comment: `apply` is not a great choice for a data.frame, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns gives reasons and alternatives